# CSS not linking to xHTML

Tags: css, xhtml, linker

though I have visited this site many times, this is my first question.

After hours of google-foo to no avail, I cannot get my stylesheet to link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN” “http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd”>

<html xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml” lang=”en” xml:lang=”en”>
<head>

    <title>Newb Development</title>

    <link type=“text/css” rel="stylesheet" href=”\master.css” />

</head>

<body>

    <img src="banner.gif" alt="NewbDev Logo" title="Newb Development" />
    <h1>Welcome To NewbDev.com</h1>

    <h2>Under Construction</h2>
    <p>
    As you can see, we are currently under construction.  Upon completion
    of the website you will be able to follow a fellow newb developer
    on his journey to <em>programming masterification!</em>
    </p>

</body>
```

The file "master.css" is in the same directory.  I have tried it on the computer and via the server and my styles are not applying.  I know I do not have to style sheet posted here but it's nothing fancy and I'm positive the contents of stylesheet are not the issue.

Comment: Is the css file indeed located at that location, in the root of your domain? Does it work right when you make it HTML instead of XHTML? And can we see your site?

Comment: You've got some funky speech mark characters in there, not sure if that would be a problem. Otherwise, try the path with a forward slash (assuming that your css file is in the web root) `href="/master.css"`

Comment: Does it work if you move the "\" from the link href (ensuring master.css is in the same directory has the html file)?

Comment: @shanethehat Speech marks? What do you mean? You are probably spot on with the backslash though.

Comment: The quotes are wrong. Fix them..

Comment: `alt="NewbDev Logo"` — The alt attribute should be a [replacement for an image, not a description of it](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html#howlers).

Comment: @Quentin but the logo itself contains of the words "Newb Dev"

Comment: @MrLister — Does the logo contain the word "Logo"? Is the purpose of the logo to express the information "This is a logo!" or "This is something to do with "Newb Dev"?

Comment: @Quentin It pretty much says nothing but "I'm a logo", yes. It even appears all on top, before the `h1`, before the page really begins.

Comment: @MrLister — But the purpose of it is to brand the page. The information in the image is "Newb Dev". Being a logo is not the message, just how it communicates it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use backslash in URL's.

Try this instead, if your CSS-file is available at the root:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/master.css" />
```

Comment: Ah yea, that was a try and error I did a few minutes ago and forgot to restore.  But the "/master.css" does not work either.

Comment: @user1291532 Does your CSS-file exist in the web-root? If you try to access the file through it's URL via the browser, is it available?

Comment: @user1291532 So is the html file in the root of your domain too? You did say it was in the same directory.

Comment: newbdev.com/master.css    it's there

Comment: @user1291532 Then my second guess would be that it is your quotation marks. You should use `"` instead of `”`. If you look in the Dev-tools of your browser, does the CSS-file get loaded?

Comment: They are in the same directory ^^  This has been driving me crazy.  I have dabbled in a few programming languages and just today decided to try some webdev.  It's proving more frustrating than any other language I have (attempted) to learn.

Comment: Thanks Christofer!  I guess I copied and pasted that line somewhere, I just assumed that was notepad++'s doing.  Thanks to everyone else too!  The feedback was about 1000x faster than I assumed it would be.  I'll definitely be back for any other newbie problems I might run across.

Answer (score 5):

> The file "master.css" is in the same directory.

So you should have `href="master.css"` not `href="/master.css"` or `href="\master.css"`.

Also note the quotes, you need `"` or `'` not `”`. (You might need to zoom in to see the difference):

## `" ' ”`

A [validator](http://validator.w3.org) would pick up that last problem.

Comment: I was under the impression that a forward slash pointed towards root.  But that doesn't work either. I've pretty much tried all these suggestions already.  At least I know I'm not just being oblivious =)

Answer (score 0):

Since your master.css is in the same directory just use:

```
<link type=“text/css” rel="stylesheet" href=”master.css” />
```

If that doesn't work make sure it is saved as a css file.